# Start a timer in a service

Tags: java, android, service, timer, chronometer

How can I start a chronometer in a service?

I ask this because you can't associate an XML file to a service

```
Chronometer mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
```

My goal is to vibrate phone after the prox sensor has been keep covered for at least 5 seconds.

Comment: You want to do it in background ?

Comment: I have my service working, with onNear() method. When an object is near the proximity sensor, onNear is called. In onNear i would like to start a chronometer and do something if the object is still near the sensor when chronometer reaches 5 seconds.

Comment: So start activity from `onNear()` method. and in this activity get the Chronometer and do work as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In onNear i would like to start a chronometer and do something if the object is still near the sensor when chronometer reaches 5 seconds.

`Chronometer` is a widget. It is part of the user interface. Services do not have a user interface. Services do not use widgets. Services do not use `Chronometer`.

Use `Timer` and `TimerTask` to get control after five seconds within a service.

Comment: Could you give me an example for my case? Thanks

Comment: `Timer` and `TimerTask` are part of standard Java. Newcomers to Android should learn Java first before starting Android development.

Comment: How did you make this? I am with the same issue.